# Default Company in VB

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Windows xp sp3, that I inherited and the computer has a company that I don't have nor own and when I open visual basic I have to go and change the company name every time...

is there a way to change the default company so I don't have to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems better suited for Super User. But in the interest of saving time...
If I understand your question correctly this is what you need: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310441